# How to properly catch events using MochaJs

Tags: truffle, contract-debugging, events, testing, mocha

Good day,

I'm using mochajs to test my Solidity code using truffle and testrpc.

In my contract I got the following event and function:

```
contract store{
    event MoneyIn (address _from, uint256 _amount);

    function getMoney() payable{
        //event
        MoneyIn(msg.sender, msg.value);
    } 
}
```

And this is the mochajs code:

```
it("Pay to store", function(){
    return storeContract.getMoney({from: account[0], value: txAmount}).then(function(res){
      assert.isDefined(res);
    });
});
```

It simpally checks if the transaction was executed by checking if the `res` is defined.

However, when mocha don't throw errors, it also won't emit the event. The only way in which I can get see my event is my creating an error:
for example I can change the assertion from `isDefined(res)` to `ifError(res)`.

Doing so will force mocha to throw an error and as a side product it will also emit my event:

```
1) Pay to store

Events emitted during test:
---------------------------

MoneyIn(_to: 0xa86120c19324a9ed51fe17730fce24edd69ddc9c, _amount: 300000000000000000)

---------------------------
```

I'll hihgly appriciate any tip you might have on how to force mocha to emit events even when there're no errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Explanation:**

This functionality is not available in Truffle at the moment, as logged events are not displayed on passing tests ([source code](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/blob/8b1846aaa2dd401bc5842e4cd4e812363b31304d/lib/testing/testrunner.js#L138-L140)).

I like the idea of tracking events on passing tests as well, and it seems Truffle will eventually have this feature ([tracking issue](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/186)).

**Workaround:**

One way to show the events is to simply watch them as per the [web3 API](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-allevents), and do a `console.log` (see the example code I have linked).

Comment: I did use console.log for some of my tests, but as they're usually presented at the TOP of the current execution, I decided against (It was really hard to follow them in the right order). I'm somewhat glad to know that currently, that's just the way it works. I spent days trying to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You could try something like [this](https://github.com/DeviateFish/Lotto/blob/master/test/unit/lottery_round_factory.js#L72-L80).  This is in embark, but it also uses mocha, so this sort of thing should work out of the box for making assertions on events from contracts.

[`getEvent`](https://github.com/DeviateFish/Lotto/blob/master/test/unit/lottery_round_factory.js#L32-L35) itself is pretty straightforward

Answer (score 1):

In web3.js version 1 the solution is similar to what @travis-jacobs proposes:

```
it('school "AtAddress" event was emitted and equal to call result', async () => {
    const events = await school.getPastEvents('AtAdress');
    const addressFromEvent = events[0].returnValues['loc'];
    assert.equal(courseAddress, addressFromEvent);
});
```

See a complete example [here](https://github.com/0xUX/play/blob/712d98ec9f444da1921131b1b87a6804aec05eb0/ethereum/test/Course.test.js#L51).

Note that web3-beta-35 and below can't handle events with indexed parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, my `truffle-assertions` library also offers the ability to log all emitted events inside a transaction in the same way as truffle outputs them on error.

The library can be installed through npm

```
npm install truffle-assertions
```

Then, it can be imported at the top of your test file

```
const truffleAssert = require('truffle-assertions');
```

And finally it can be used to output all emitted events inside a transaction.

```
let result = storeContract.getMoney({from: account[0], value: txAmount});
truffleAssert.prettyPrintEmittedEvents(result);
```